# How to pass data's through ajax if that variable have any values

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following is my code for ajax,

```
$( ".location" ).on( "click", function(){
    var loc = $('.location:checked').map(function(_, el) {
        return $(el).val();
    }).get();
    if($(".hedu").is(':checked'))
    {
        var edu = $('.hedu:checked').map(function(_, el) {
            return $(el).val();
        }).get();
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'search_cv_result',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            edu:edu,
            loc: loc,
            fltr:"ftr"
        },
        success: function(data) {
        $('.course_list').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Here,I pass `loc` variable and also another `edu` variable ..

The `edu` value is either null or not null.

If it is null I don't want to send that `edu` value through ajax..

I tried something like this..

```
        data: {
            if(edu != ''){
            edu:edu,}
            loc: loc,
            fltr:"ftr"
        },
```

But I think it's not correct method..And also it show me an error..

How should I do this..Someone help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (loc === 'undefined' || loc === null) {
        var _data  = { loc: loc, fltr: 'ftr' };
    } 
    else {
        var _data = { edu: edu, loc: loc, fltr: 'ftr' };
    }

    $.ajax({
       url: 'search_cv_result',
        type: 'GET',
        data: _data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('In Ajax');
        }
    });
```